# how to play video with vlc via terminal to view on webpage?

Tags: vlc

Now have VLC installed ,how to play a video with vlc via terminal running centos 6 to be viewed on website? What is the command to test it?

I want to use VLC on my website which resides on my VPS set up with Linux Centos so I can play videos. But after installing VLC, I don't know how to make it so I can see those videos on my website. I don't know what steps to take from play something on vlc via terminal to view it on my site.

I don't even know how to get a video playing via terminal now it is installed because all the different commands just seem to do nothing.

I need a head start....how do I open up the player? so I can view it on my server?

Comment: if you want to set up a streaming server I can only advice you to install madsonic or subsonic who are real streaming server really powerful and much more easy to setup in my opinion

Comment: Where have you got VLC installed ?

Comment: on my vps which i connect to remotely via terminal

Comment: Removed many, many comments. If you want to argue about how forum-like SE is, use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is actually a website, you can embed it using HTML5 video - you will need a more recent version of a browser to use it. There is in an example of it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Jg8L/).

For VLC, there are instructions for streaming [here](https://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch02.html), with command line versions [here](https://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch03.html).

Comment: will look at this another day-soon, thanks :)

Comment: but will give you the answer for html5 option in the meantime- cheers

Comment: [Please include the basics of the solution in your actual post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/203101). Answers that simply point to external resources are frowned upon on this site.